# C++ strange namespace lookup behavior

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

```
namespace fooo {
  class Fooo {
  public:
    int a;
  };
}

namespace fooo {
  class Test {
  public:
    Test(Fooo::Fooo *i) {
      i->a = 1;
    }
  };
}
```

This code compiles fine with clang (any version) but fails with gcc.
Can anyone explain why?

EDIT:
Yes, I know the issue here is kinda obvious but why does clang accept it? The person who told me this said that this is a bug in the standard and that there is a Defect Report. Can anyone point to the actual DR?

Comment: Didn't gcc tell you? It usually shows a diagnostic message if compilation fails.

Comment: error: ‘fooo::Fooo::Fooo’ names the constructor, not the type

Comment: Even if the first Fooo is a typo: error: assignment of member ‘fooo::Fooo::a’ in read-only object

Comment: Ah, that's that old class name injected in class definition thing. Usually, clang is wrong in this iirc, but I don't remember the specifics. Let me see if I can find a dupe.

Comment: Sorry, I removed the const.

Comment: Yes I know the issue here but why does clang accept it? The person who told me this said that this is an bug in the standard and that there is a Defect Report.

Comment: Yep, unfixed clang bug indeed. There are links to existing bug reports in the dupe answer.

Comment: @Edit: Read the answers in the dupe, there are links to the clang bugs and to the defect report.

Answer (score 0):

The error message from gcc tells you exactly what the problem is:

```
t.cpp:11:16: error: ‘fooo::Fooo::Fooo’ names the constructor, not the type
     Test(const Fooo::Fooo *i) {
                ^
```

it is suprising that clang doesn't give an error.